# Improving the search system

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, search

When recognizing some questions as duplicates, sometimes it is difficult to find the original question one remembers. For instance, I recently saw a question asking to prove that
$$\forall x\in(-1,1),\qquad \log(1+x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}z^n. $$
If we try to search `$\log(1+x)$` we can see that the parenthesis are stripped, so the system looks for questions containing `\log1` and finds nothing. One can circumvent this issue by searching `$\log (1+x)$` and being luckier. Anyway I think that the search system is quite far from being efficient, especially about $\LaTeX$ support.

Do you have any ideas about improving it?

Comment: Not a suggestion for improving built-in search, but entering `taylor log(1+x) site:math.stackexchange.com` in Google gives desired results. ([This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/12054/147263) in particular)

Comment: @Fundamental: I wonder if it is the case to add a "search through Google" option, or just fix the parser.

Comment: Even if math parsing is improved, I don't expect the free [elasticsearch engine](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) to match the capability of a multi-billion enterprise. The built-in search  is great for filtering on tags, score, and other SE-specific parameters. For full-text search, not so great.

Comment: Try http://uniquation.com/en/ (A suggestion posted in this meta thread: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388/feature-request-better-full-text-search-capabilities-within-tex-markup).

Comment: Just as an inspiratino: There is kind of a 'backwards' math search website here: http://searchonmath.com Try e.g. `\frac 4 n = \frac 1 a + \frac 1 b + \frac 1 c `.

Comment: It is easy to find relevant posts containing expressions like this on approach0.xyz: 
https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clog(1%2Bx)%3D%5Csum_%7Bn%5Cgeq%201%7D%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7Bn%7Dz%5En%24&p=1

Comment: In connection with the previous @WeiZhong's comment it is worth mentioning that more complete information on that project can be found here: [Announcing a third-party search engine for Math StackExchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange).